# Stopped aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a free account since more time to test aws services. Last week I started 2 ec2 instances and I created an EKS cluster. After one day I found 26€ as billing.
I removed all EC2 instances, the cluster EKS, the users that I created them, the users-group, I deleted every thing from the account. But the billing is still increasing without any running service. Now I have 40€. I created an incident to aws support but I don't now when they will answer me.

Do you have an idea please ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see exactly what you are being billed for by visiting the billing console. If you look at the [bills](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/bills) page it will default to the current month.

Comment: It mentined that EC2 and EKS. But I removed every thing. I stoped / terminated also the EC2

Comment: If you are still being charged for those services then you haven't removed everything.

Comment: I closed the account